# Function which is everywhere discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is there a function $f:R\to R$ that satisfies

1. $f$ is everywhere discontinuous.
2. $\lim_{h \to 0}(f(a+h)-f(a-h))=0$ for all $a \in R$

Comment: No. See my answer to [Does $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\ [f(x+h)-f(x-h)]=0$ imply that $f$ is continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165864/13130)