# Is there a difference between $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}f(p+h)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Are these limits equivalent?
$$
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f(x) \\\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}f(p+h)
$$
They both describe $f(x)$ as $x$ gets arbitrarily close to $p$, but I see both used in different contexts so I'm wondering if there is actually a difference between the two. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to have the second limit be $\lim_{h \to 0^+}{f(p+h)}$?

Comment: @Hayden.  I changed the question, hopefully it makes sense now. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164723/does-lim-h-rightarrow-0-fxh-fx-h-0-imply-that-f-is-continuous) problem from baby Rudin is what lead me ask this question.

Comment: no deep maths facts here. Just make the algebraic substitution x=p+h

Comment: They're exactly the same. It's just that sometimes one of the two is easier to do calculations with.

Answer (score 3):

They are actually the same. 
Let $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow p}f(x)=l\in \mathbb R$. What existence of this limit means is that for every $\epsilon\gt 0,\exists \delta\gt 0: 0\lt |x-p|\lt \delta\implies |f(x)-l|\lt \epsilon$ 
WLOG, put $x=p+h$ so that we have $0\lt |h| \lt \delta\implies |f(p+h)-l|\lt \epsilon$ 
Now use definition of limit again to finish the proof.