# If $\lim\limits_{h\to0 } f(x+h)- f(x-h)= 0$ how to prove that there are at most countable set of discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I saw this problem : Suppose $f$ is a real function defined on $\mathbb{R}^1$ which satisfies $\lim\limits_{h\to0 } f(x+h)- f(x-h)= 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^1$  Does this imply that $f$ is continuous?

I tried for an hour to prove that $f$ is continuous and failed to (I was very upset because I thought that this function is continuous and I was not able to prove that.) I decided to see the solution and to my surprise the function is not continuous.

That made me wonder how much discontinuities  could this function  have and I made a claim that is at most countable. I tried to prove this claim but failed to. I hope that this claim is not false (not the same way my first intuition was false )

Comment: See [Does $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\ [f(x+h)-f(x-h)]=0$ imply that $f$ is continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164723/13130). In my answer I discuss some properties and possible counterexamples of such functions, in particular the fact that such a function can have $\mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0}$ (i.e. continuum many) discontinuities (in fact, even a Hausdorff dimension $1$ set of discontinuities) in every interval containing more than one point.